# How can I make some items in a ListBox bold?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, listbox

In Visual c# Express Edition, is it possible to make some (but not all) items in a ListBox  bold? I can't find any sort of option for this in the API.

Comment: Are you on WPF? In which case, it's much easier

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a bit of a .NET newbie, I'm not even sure what WPF is.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to change listbox's DrawMode to DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed. Check out these articles on msdn:
[DrawMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drawmode.aspx)
[ListBox.DrawItem Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx)
[Graphics.DrawString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19sb1bw6.aspx)

Also look at this question on msdn forums:
[Question on ListBox items](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/dacea8cd-963e-4a40-9af6-1495acf1d3c5/)

A simple example (both items - Black-Arial-10-Bold):

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(new Object[] { "First Item", "Second Item"});
        ListBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    }

    private void ListBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
 }
```

Comment: `e.Graphics.DrawString()` is a very troubled method, you should really avoid it. All Windows Forms controls, including ListBox, use `TextRenderer.DrawText()`. That solves the problem when I start resizing the form at the runtime

Answer (score 2):

To add to Mindaugas Mozūras's solution, I had a problem where my `e.Bounds` wasn't large enough and text was getting cut off. To solve this problem (thanks to a post [here](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=314206)), you override the `OnMeasureItem` event and changes your DrawMode to `DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable`.

In designer:

```
listBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
```

In handler:

```
void listBox_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
     e.ItemHeight = 18;
}
```

Solved my issues of having the height cut off text.

Comment: Just adding on to say that I didn't have this problem on my development computer, but we did get it when shipping to a terminal server. So I strongly recommend applying this to your code for safety.

Answer (score 1):

A more generic example that uses sender, and actually respects foreground color (if the item is selected, for example, or the user uses some another color set, where black foreground color is not really readable) and current ListBox font:

```
    private void listBoxDrawItem (object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Font f = e.Font;
        if (e.Index == 1) //TODO: Your condition to make text bold
            f = new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.Graphics.DrawString(((ListBox)(sender)).Items[e.Index].ToString(), f, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

You need to have DrawMode set to OwnerDrawFixed (for example, in designer).

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code demonstrating the same.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (FontFamily fam in FontFamily.Families)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(fam.Name);
            }
            listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed; // 属性里设置

        }

        private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            e.DrawBackground();
            e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), new Font(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), listBox1.Font.Size), Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);
            //e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Sample Output]

Answer (score 0):

Make the selected item bold

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(new Object[] { "me", "myself", "bob"});

        // set the draw mode to fixed
        ListBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    }

    private void ListBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // draw the background
        e.DrawBackground();

        // get the font
        Font font = new Font(e.Font, (e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected ? FontStyle.Bold : FontStyle.Regular);

        // draw the text
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), font, new SolidBrush(ListBox1.ForeColor), e.Bounds);

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
}
```