# How to bold a text line in listbox, when click a button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listbox

I'm writing a program in Visual Studio 2013, making a windows form application.
there is a listbox with some string items, a textbox and a button.
I will enter an integer number to the textbox, and then press the button. 
Everytime the button has been press, only the line indicated by the number in the textbox will be **BOLD** 
Can anyone help me, please!
Sorry for the bad English

Comment: That's a requirement specification and not a question. What's the question?

Comment: You need to hook the `DrawItem` event of the listbox, there you can draw your string with a certain font and style (like **bold**, what you wanted), see http://stackoverflow.com/a/327320/5296568 . Combine this with some static variable like `int currUnderlinedLine` and you should get it to work dynamically.

Comment: In addition to coding the DrawItem event you also need to set the lb.DraWMode to some OwnerDraw mode!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make some items in a ListBox bold?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327310/how-can-i-make-some-items-in-a-listbox-bold)